# Invalid Json response in codeigniter php

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, codeigniter

I want to insert a data table to my website. I'm using Codeigniter here for php. 
As mentioned in [datatables manual](http://datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/1) I did as directed and there is nothing wrong with the json object that is returned (used developer tool to grab the json object). I validated it with **JsonLint** as well and it is valid. But I still get the error saying '**Invalid Json response**'.

> **Invalid Json response**

This is the javascript in my view.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#table1').dataTable({
        "sAjaxSource": "http://localhost/project/index.php/conM/loadMarks"
    });
});
```

And the table's id is 'table1'. Can someone please suggest me something?

Answer (score 0):

your Json Source should like the following example

```
{"draw":0,"recordsTotal":4,"recordsFiltered":4,"data":[["2","3q","qww","Active"],["3","wert","erthj","Active"],["5","testdata","test description","Active"],["6","wertyh","asdfgh","Active"]]}
```

can you copy paste the ajax source for better help